# JS - keydown event is empty on typing backspace Android chrome mobile (4.4)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, input, keycode

I'm expecting an issue on Android 4.4 while trying to restrict input to only numbers on `input` field.

That's fired on Backbone event `'keydown .js-text' : 'setText'`:

```
setText: (e) ->
  console.log e #it is empty when clicking "backspace"
  charCode = e.keyCode or e.charCode
  if charCode > 31 and (charCode < 48 or charCode > 57) and charCode isnt 8 and (charCode < 96 or charCode > 105)
    return false
```

Also I see that on `keydown` event is empty when clicking backspace

Comment: if you what that user will available enter a number only thane use something like this editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);